# Distinguish English and Spanish with regular expressions

Tags: code-golf, natural-language, regular-expression

The task is to to compete for the **shortest regex** (in **bytes**) in your preferred programming language which can distinguish between English and Spanish with minimum <s>**`60%`**</s> **`90%`** accuracy.

[Silvio Mayolo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/207418/95389)'s submission (pinned as `Best Answer`) has secured his spot as the winner of original contest against any chance of being contested.  In order to provide room for further submissions, he has generously allowed the scoring requirement to be pushed to 90% accuracy.

## Links to wordlists have been replaced due to concerns voiced in the comments.

The following word lists (based on [these](https://github.com/words/an-array-of-spanish-words)) must be used: [English](https://github.com/GirkovArpa/english-spanish-wordlists/blob/master/en_clean.json), [Spanish](https://github.com/GirkovArpa/english-spanish-wordlists/blob/master/es_clean.json)

The Spanish wordlist is already transliterated into ASCII, and there is no word present in either which is also present in the other.

A naive approach to distinguishing Spanish from English might be to match if the word ends in a vowel:

## `[aeiou]$` `i` <sup>9 bytes</sup>

Here's a live example, where `6` of `8` words are successfully identified, for `75%` accuracy:

```js
const regex = /[aeiou]$/i;

const words = [
  'hello',
  'hola',
  'world',
  'mundo',
  'foo',
  'tonto',
  'bar',
  'barra'
];

words.forEach(word => {
  const match = word.match(regex);
  const langs = ['English', 'Spanish'];
  const lang = langs[+!!match];
  console.log(word, lang);
});
```

Comment: (Assuming I understand right that we need to choose two languages and have our code distinguish just those two) I suspect too much of the challenge hinges on finding languages with very stereotypical distinct common patterns within ASCII characters. I'd suspect at this point the regexp's will be simple and golfing them won't be that interesting.

Comment: I changed the rules to use only the English and Spanish wordlists, so that the challenge can be focused on golfing regex instead of finding dissimilar languages.

Comment: Thanks, I like these changes. Could you please also make a link an ASCII-transliterated Spanish word list? I'm not clear though on how our accuracy is judged. Are we given a word from one of the two word lists (20,000 words total) and our regex judges if it's English of Spanish, with us choosing which one is "match" and "not match"? What about if the string happens to appears in both lists?

Comment: When you say shortest regex in any language, does that only count the length of the regex string in that flavor? Or does it count the invocation like `re.match(...)` as well?

Comment: That's some good points, I'll make and link a version of the transliterated wordlists with shared words removed.  By shortest regex in bytes I mean counting only the regex itself.  So for instance in JavaScript you can see my example was `[aeiou]$` `i` even though that `RegExp` literal would be written as `/[aeiou]$/i`, and was used as `.match(...)`.  I am not a regex expert and this is my first contest so if there are any problems with that please let me know.

Comment: I think this is an interesting challenge, but it needs some refinement. We have a Sandbox on the Meta site (if someone can link to it, I'm on mobile now) for just such a purpose.

Comment: Sandbox Link: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges

Comment: This was in the Sandbox yesterday.

Comment: The Spanish list has the accents and tildes removed - was this intentional?

Comment: Yes, as stated in the OP: `The Spanish wordlist is already transliterated into ASCII`.  Testing for non-English characters would be cheap, don't you think?

Comment: Maybe we could use a different scoring system for this one, since it apparently has a fairly unbeatable answer. Accuracy squared multiplied by byte count?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo What do you think? Your answer would remain pinned as `Best Answer` for posterity, while allowing future submissions to compete with the rules `mypetlion` suggested.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not going to be offended if you change the winning condition. My answer is amusing, but it's not like I worked very hard for it. :P Factoring in accuracy should make things very interesting.

Comment: Awesome, I appreciate that =) I will update the rules.

Comment: @mypetlion Did you mean divided by byte count?

Comment: My experience with length-accuracy trade-off scoring formulas is that they're almost always turn out unbalanced or exploitable by answers caring for pretty much just about the one or the other. Moreover, dividing by byte count is usually a bad idea that rewards ultra-short answers when the other factor has a cap. I'd suggest just putting a higher required goal accuracy.

Comment: Okay I will put this post in limbo until I figure something out.

Comment: Regarding the Sandbox, it's good that you posted there first, but one day is too little time to gather feedback. Three days minimum is usually recommended by default, but with this being not a bog-standard code golf but a challenge with a test battery, I'd suggest a week or two at least.

Comment: That metric may not quite be enough. A 2-byte answer can beat my answer if it has accuracy of 84% or above (which *may* be possible with 2 bytes, but I'm not hopeful). A 3-byte or more answer, even with 100% accuracy, can only get a 0.33 score, at most. I like this challenge, but I'm not sure what the right metric for it is, to be honest.

Comment: I'm looking at a scripted list of possible scores right now and yeah I definitely see what you mean.  I edited the OP to say the challenge is frozen until a scoring method can be decided on.

Comment: @GirkovArpa Oh right yeah, divided by, because we want a lower score to win. I was thinking backwards.

Comment: @GirkovArpa Actually, hold on, I think we've both got it wrong. It should be `byte count` / `accuracy squared`. Because a 60% accuracy squared is 0.36. So a 2 byte answer would get a score of 5.555... Whereas a 3 byte answer with the same accuracy would get a score of 8.333...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "This contest is frozen until a reasonable scoring system can be decided on."

Comment: There's also https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19041/is-a-solution-wins-if-theres-no-strictly-better-solution-in-multiple-measures ... but (you see the votes yourself. Bubbler's answer is at +3/-3.)

Comment: (regarding the "3 days": it *is* written in the "sandbox FAQ", but... nobody read that?)

Comment: i'll vote to close because the contest is frozen for now.

Comment: Also I think you should provide the lists as plaintext files, one word per line, rather than JSON.

Comment: maybe you an ask for shortest code with 90% accuracy or something like that

Comment: Not sure how important it is for the challenge, but the Spanish list includes a lot of words that are not Spanish: _yyo_, _kallen_, _ilama_, _yankee_, _oscorp_, _missy_, _vinci_, _tirith_, _hagrid_, _spike_, _finch_, _vaako_, _tj_, _deb_, as well as some possibly proper nouns that don't sound Spanish at all: _isabelle_, _ani_, _shirley_, _ashford_, _ming_, _asher_, _gwen_, _brett_, _jess_, _kenobi_, _dickens_, _dexter_, _marcy_, _lizzy_, _kiddo_, _olaf_, _poe_, _bert_, _klaus_. And I only glanced at the last 500 words in the list...

Comment: @qwr That is a good solution, short and easy to understand.

Comment: @LuisMendo They are supposedly the `10` `000` most common words in the Spanish language, according to the repository I got them from (I did remove words that existed in both the English and Spanish wordlists).  Although, now that you mention Hagrid, I'm having my doubts.  Is Harry Potter really that common?

Comment: @GirkovArpa I'm a native Spanish speaker and I see words in that list that I don't recognize as common, and definitely not as Spanish words

Comment: If you follow the citation here: https://github.com/oprogramador/most-common-words-by-language It seems the wordlists are derived from Wiktionary.  I am not sure how the frequencies were determined though.

Comment: I updated the rules with the suggestion from @qwr.  I hope this can be re-opened.

Comment: To be a little specific on LuisMendo's comment, "ei" is not a Spanish word, and is not even on wiktionary.  It is the sort of word that appears as a transcripcion error from "El" or "Él".  I also notice at least one slightly vulgar word, "carajo" which basically means "dick", on the Spanish list.  I don't know if you care about that.

Comment: I am not overly attached to these particular wordlists.  If there are better alternatives I'm willing to link those instead.

Comment: @GirkovArpa I'm not sure how  github.com/oprogramador/most-common-words-by-language construct its word list. I had just checked the Chinese language version. It claimed the word "the" is a common word in Chinese language. (wtf

Comment: I suggest using wordlists if the most common words in a language which you should easily be able to find.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Any Language, 0.3677 (60.6064%, 1 byte)

```
a
```

No, I'm not joking. The single-character regular expression `a` successfully identifies Spanish words over English given your input files 60.6064% of the time, which makes it a valid submission.

Here's a complete, runnable Perl script that checks the percentage of this regular expression, assuming you've downloaded `english.json` and `spanish.json` into the same folder as the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @english;
my @spanish;

my $fh;
open $fh, '<', 'english.json';
while (<$fh>) {
    push @english, $1 if /"(\w+)"/;
}
close $fh;

open $fh, '<', 'spanish.json';
while (<$fh>) {
    push @spanish, $1 if /"(\w+)"/;
}
close $fh;

my $correct = 0;
my $total = 0;

my $re = qr/a/;

for (@english) {
    $total++;
    $correct++ unless /$re/;
}
for (@spanish) {
    $total++;
    $correct++ if /$re/;
}

say "$correct / $total (@{[100*$correct/$total]}%)";
```

Comment: Good job!  That's fascinating that just having the letter `a` makes a word significantly more likely to be Spanish as opposed to English.  Also, maybe I should have consulted a linguist to review the OP before submission :P

Comment: Well, can't imagine anybody's going to beat that...

Comment: Also amazing how it just barely qualified by `0.6%` percentage points.

Comment: It's also the only letter that satisfies the criteria. The next best would be `o`, with 58.69%, then it drops way down to 54.08% with `t`. On the flipside, `n` occurs most uniformly, at 50.13% accuracy.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, I was curious to know.  Was `a` actually the first thing you tried?

Comment: I wrote a script to analyze common character sequences in the two files, in the hopes of finding a 3- or 4-character constant regex that would do it. Sure enough, my script came back with `a`, which made me chuckle.

Answer (score 4):

## 50 bytes, 90.02% accurate

`(a(d?|is|r|se?)|dor|eis|ese|je|n|[ns]te|os?|res?)$`

For 18,004 out of the 20,000 words in `es_clean.json` and `en_clean.json`, this regex matches iff the input word is Spanish.